# How can i use waitForCondition() function using FirefoxDriver Object?

Tags: java, ajax, firefox, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am new to Selenium testing.
I am using FireFoxDriver for developing automated testcases.
Do we have any option of using waitForCondition() method using FireFoxDriver Object?
My application is based on ajax and i need to select the dropdown list that is generated by AJAX.

Please HELP

Answer (score 2):

By http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually implement it, something like:

```
bool condition = false;
while (!condition)
{
   try
   {
      condition = ...
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
   }      
   Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

the try-catch block lets you use FindElement to search of a specific element (in this case your dropdown list).

Alternatively you can set the timeout time like so:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
```

Any call will automatically keep trying to find the necessary elements for the amount of time you specified before throwing an exception